# Postgresql with Power Query

Tags: excel, postgresql, powerquery

I am a Postgresql newbie and try to use a view with Excel Power Query.
I am able to see only Tables with Power Query. 
I do not see any views inside Power Query. 
I have given the ACL access for everyone.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "xx" AS   SELECT * from test;

ALTER TABLE "xx"   OWNER TO postgres; GRANT ALL ON TABLE "xx" TO
postgres; GRANT ALL ON TABLE "xx" TO public;
```

What am I missing so that the views can be found inside Excel?

Edit: I have found a workaround using the SQL statement when defining the data source - thus it looks like an Excel Power query bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there was a bug in Power Query. Sorry about that, but thanks for bringing it up!

Look for a fix in an October update (sooner if you are using Power BI Desktop).